# How to if conditions between two intents in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sensors, gpio

Рow to use if statements between two intent activities? I have two different activities collecting data from external sensors. I would like to control some GPIO pins of `Activity1` based on the sensor values of `Activity2`.

##### Activity 1

```
public class RealTimeData extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "sensor_data";
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_real_time_data);

        Resources res = getResources();
        GetAllResources();
        OpenSerialPort();

    }

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    private void GetAllResources() {


        pressure1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressure);
        temp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperature);
        co2ppm1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.co2);
        humidity1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidity);

        pressure1data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressureData);
        temp1data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureData);
        co2ppm1data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.co2Data);
        humidity1data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidityData);

    }


    private sensorDataApplication sensordata = new sensorDataApplication();


    private UartApplication[] mSerialport = {null, null};

    private void SetValues()
    {
        TextView tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressureData);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(sensordata.get_pressure_value(0)));
        tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureData);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(sensordata.get_temperature_value(0)));
        tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.co2Data);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(sensordata.get_co2_value(0)));
        tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidityData);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(sensordata.get_humidity_value(0)));
    }

    private void OpenSerialPort() {

        new sensorDataApplication();

        try {
            int i =0;
            for(String devicePath : Configs.uartdevicePath) {
                mSerialport[i] = new UartApplication(new File(devicePath), mReaderCallback);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            ErrorMessage.newInstance(getString(R.string.error_serial))
                    .show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorMessage.newInstance(getString(R.string.error_unknown))
                    .show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } catch (InvalidParameterException e) {
            ErrorMessage.newInstance(getString(R.string.error_uart_config))
                    .show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    private final UartApplication.ReaderCallback mReaderCallback=
            new UartApplication.ReaderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onDataReceived(final byte[] buffer, final int size) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (pressure1 != null) {
                                String received_str = new String(buffer, 0, size);
                                //uartRx.append(received_str);
                                sensordata.parse_and_update_sensordata(received_str);
                                SetValues();
                                Log.e(TAG,"received packet "+received_str);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    TextWatcher mUartTxCallback = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(max(start,before) < s.length()) {
                String changedStr = s.toString().substring(max(start, before), s.length());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable var1) {
        }
    };

    private void CloseSerialPort(int idx)
    {
        mSerialport[idx].closeSerialPort();
    }

    private void WriteSerialPort(String writeString, int idx)
    {
        mSerialport[idx].writeData(writeString);
    }



    private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        s.toUpperCase();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static String toHexString(byte[] ba) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++)
            str.append(String.format("%02x", ba[i]));
        return str.toString().toUpperCase();
    }


    private TextView pressure1;
    private TextView temp1;
    private TextView co2ppm1;
    private TextView humidity1;

    private TextView pressure1data;
    private TextView temp1data;
    private TextView co2ppm1data;
    private TextView humidity1data;


}
```

##### Activity 2

```
public class ManualControl extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    List<gpioApplication> mGPIO = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";
    private int[] mGPIOList = null;
    private CheckBox[] cbGPIO;


    private final gpioApplication.InterruptCallback mGPIOCallback =
            new gpioApplication.InterruptCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onDataReceived(final int GPIOnum, final int value) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //Do Nothing
                            CheckBox cbnGPIO = GetCheckBoxGpio(GPIOnum);
                            cbnGPIO.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                            if (cbnGPIO != null)
                                cbnGPIO.setChecked(value > 0 ? true : false);
                            cbnGPIO.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mGPIOCheckBoxCallback);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    private final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mGPIOCheckBoxCallback =
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    //do stuff
                    int gpioID = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getHint().toString());
                    int GPIOValue = buttonView.isChecked() == true ? 1 : 0;
                    if (gpioID < mGPIOList.length) {
                        gpioApplication gpio = mGPIO.get(gpioID);
                        gpio.GPIOWrite(GPIOValue);
                    }
                }
            };


    private CheckBox GetCheckBoxGpio(int GPIOnum) {
        if (GPIOnum < mGPIOList.length)
            return cbGPIO[GPIOnum];
        return null;
    }


    private void GetAllResources() {

        cbGPIO = new CheckBox[20];

        cbGPIO[9] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_GPIO92);
        cbGPIO[0] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_GPIO16);
        cbGPIO[1] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_GPIO17);
        cbGPIO[6] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_GPIO69);
        cbGPIO[2] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_GPIO23);
        for (int i = 0; i < mGPIOList.length; i++) {
            if (i == 9 || i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 6 || i == 2) {
                GetCheckBoxGpio(i).setText(Integer.toString(mGPIOList[i]));
                GetCheckBoxGpio(i).setEnabled(true);
            }


        }


    }

    private final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mIntCheckBoxCallback =
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    //do stuff
                    int gpioID = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getHint().toString());
                    boolean IntValue = buttonView.isChecked();
                    if (gpioID < mGPIOList.length) {
                        /*Use IntValue Re-configure GPIO Interrupt Here*/
                        mGPIO.get(gpioID).ConfigureInterrupt(IntValue);
                    }
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manual_control);
        try {

            mGPIOList = gpio_list;
            GetAllResources();
            for (int i = 0; i < mGPIOList.length; i++) {

                GPIOOpen(i);

            }

            ConfigureCallbacks();
            GetAllResources();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorMessage.newInstance(e.getLocalizedMessage())
                    .show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }

    }


    private void ConfigureCallbacks() {


        ConfigureGPIOCheckboxCallback();
    }

    private void ConfigureGPIOCheckboxCallback() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mGPIOList.length; i++) {
            if (i == 9 || i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 6 || i == 2) {
                cbGPIO[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(mGPIOCheckBoxCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private void GPIOOpen(int GPIOnum) {
        if (GPIOnum == 9 || GPIOnum == 0 || GPIOnum == 1 || GPIOnum == 6 || GPIOnum == 2) {
            mGPIO.add(new gpioApplication());
            try {
                mGPIO.get(GPIOnum).GPIOOpen(GPIOnum, mGPIOList[GPIOnum], mGPIOCallback);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                ErrorMessage.newInstance(getString(R.string.error_gpio))
                        .show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ErrorMessage.newInstance(getString(R.string.error_unknown))
                        .show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
            } catch (InvalidParameterException e) {
                ErrorMessage.newInstance(getString(R.string.error_gpio_config))
                        .show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
            }
        } else {
            mGPIO.add(null);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above codes the GPIO pins must be controlled by the co2ppm1 sensor values (If the co2ppm1 sensor value is above 2000, it must turn ON GPIO 9 pin).

Comment: There is a lot of code there! I sugest you leave out what's not relevant to the problem, maybe add some comments around the area in the code you're having issues with: how is it behaving now, what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Consider passing data through to the other activity using`intent.putExtra`.